# error in set UI title in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to change the title of an MFC window as follows:

```
BOOL CameraUI::OnInitDialog()
{
    // set ui title 
    TCHAR wintitle[100];
    _stprintf_s(wintitle, sizeof wintitle, _T("Camera %u"), (UINT) getSerialNumber());  
    SetWindowText(wintitle);
return TRUE;
}
```

When I debug I get this error at the end of the function:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'wintitle' was corrupted.
```

I am using MSVC 2008. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: You must be overflowing the buffer for wintitle.  What does that buffer look like if you step through the code?

Comment: Is this the entire code or just a snippet of it? The problem is your `wintitle` buffer is overriden, but this code does't seem to do so.

Comment: This is of course a snippet of the code..the entire code is very lengthy...but this is very much the life of 'wintitle' buffer

Comment: If you are using MFC... why not use `CString` and `CString::Format`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `sizeof winTitle` as-is.

The `_stprintf_s` function requires the number of `characters`, not the number of `bytes`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx

Since obviously you're using TCHAR, then the number of characters is as follows:

```
sizeof(winTitle) / sizeof(winTitle[0])
```

or

```
sizeof(winTitle) / sizeof(TCHAR)
```

A TCHAR in the MS world is either going to be 1 byte (if the build is MBCS) or 2 bytes (which is Unicode).

Assuming you're using Unicode, by just stating `sizeof winTitle`, you are specifying that your array can fit a maximum of 200 characters, but that is not true (display what `sizeof winTitle` gives you, and you will see it is 200).

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::string` and `std::ostringstream` instead of character buffers and sprintf. This way you can avoid buffer overruns by having these classes manage memory for you. The only time you'll need to interact with c-style strings directly is when interacting with Win32 functions.

```
std::ostringstream output;
std::string wintitle;
output << "Camera " << (UINT) getSerialNumber();
wintitle = output.str();
SetWindowText(wintitle.c_str());
return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a templated overload of `_stprintf_s` that does not require a buffer size parameter. You can write the erroneous line as

```
_stprintf_s(wintitle, _T("Camera %u"), (UINT) getSerialNumber());
```

The template will automatically deduce the correct length of the destination buffer and protect you from passing the wrong buffer size.